# Spivak Chapter 10, Problem 29 : why is this true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is as follows (verbatim) : 
Prove that it is impossible to write $x = f(x)g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

I rephrased the question as I realized it wasn't optimally worded : Prove that it is impossible to write $x = f(x)g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, where $f$ are $g$ are differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

I proved this by differentiating both sides of $x = f(x)g(x)$, which gives $1 = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$; thus when $x=0, f'(0)g(0) + f(0)g'(0) = 0 \neq 1$. However, this proof doesn't give me much insight on **why** this particular exercise is true. I am really interested in seeing a more intuitive explanation, but here are some of my attempts/hypotheses :

1. $f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$ is constant when $f$ or $g$ is constant. However, WLOG, if $f(x) = 0$, then we will have to divide by zero in order to get a function $g$ such that $x = f(x)g(x)$.
2. If we define $f(x) = \frac{x}{g(x)},$ then clearly if $g(x) = 0$ then $f$ is not even continuous at $x=0$, so $f$ would not be differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

I am more or less looking for a graphical(?), intuitive explanation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: i upvoted.  nice analysis.  interesting question.  i don't know the answer either.

Comment: This might be a possible explanation. Since $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, they can be approximated by linear functions near $x = 0$. Hence $f(x) g(x)$ looks quadratic near $0$ and vanishes faster than $x$ does.

Comment: Your attempt 2. doesn't really highlight any issues. If you say $f(x)=\frac{x}{g(x)}$ for $x\neq 0$, it's possible that $x\mapsto \frac{x}{g(x)}$ has a hole at $x=0$. In this case, you can fill in $f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{g(x)}$.

Comment: Even if there is a removable discontinuity there, I don't think $f(x) = \frac{x}{g(x)}$ will be differentiable anyway... right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have by given conditions $f(x) /x\to f'(0),g(x)/x\to g'(0)$ as $x\to 0$. Hence on multiplication we have $$\frac{f(x) g(x)} {x^2}\to f'(0)g'(0)$$ or $$\frac{1}{x}\to f'(0)g'(0)$$ which is an obvious contradiction.

---

You can translate the above argument into a more informal language. Differentiability of $f, g$ at $0$ ensures that they behave like linear functions in neighborhood of $0$ and both vanish at $0$ so we must have $$f(x) \approx ax, g(x) \approx bx$$ in some neighborhood of $0$ where $a, b$ are constants. But then $$x=f(x) g(x) \approx abx^2$$ or $$1\approx abx$$ which is absurd as right hand side can be made small by choosing $x$ small but left hand side is constant.

Comment: Very nice! I think even if I came up with the intuitive idea, my rigorous implementation would've been much messier. Do you have any suggestions for remembering and applying this idea?

Comment: @Ovi: I think much of my intuition comes from a deep/rigorous understanding of basic real analysis (thanks to Hardy for writing *A Course of Pure Mathematics*) and overall experience dealing with many problems in this area (thanks to MSE).

Comment: Ah okay thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty picture. Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and assume $h$ is continuously differentiable. Then $h'(0)=0$ so by continuity, for $\epsilon>0$ small, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that when $x\in [-\delta,\delta]$, we have $|h'(x)|\leq\epsilon$. In other words, for $x_1,x_2 \in [-\delta,\delta]$, by the mean value theorem, $|h(x_2)-h(x_1)|\leq \max_{[x_1,x_2]}|h'(x)|\, |x_2-x_1|\leq \epsilon\, |x_2-x_1|$ so $h$ is locally a contraction mapping.

Moreover, for $x\in[-\delta,\delta]$, we have
$$
|h(x)|=|h(x)-h(0)|\leq\epsilon|x|\leq \epsilon\delta\leq\delta
$$
so $h$ maps $[-\delta,\delta]$ to itself.

In conclusion, both criteria to apply Banach's fixed point theorem are met. It follows that $h$ has a unique fixed point, namely $h(0)=0$.

Comment: That is a pretty picture, but I'm not quite sure it gets at the heart of the matter. I think the OP was looking for a way to see why $h'(0) = 0$, as they derive it, but don't understand the why. Here you seem to state it as a trivial consequence of the product rule.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem here is a lack of intuition for the product rule. You apply it to derive $h'(0) = 0$, but you seem to not see intuitively why it must be $0$ and not $1$.

3Blue1Brown has a nice exposition of the general intuition behind the product rule (and the chain rule!) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG15m2VwSjA).

Thus, instead of trying to replicate that, I'll just speak about how to apply it here.

Most people will show you the following picture for the product rule:[image]

The strange thing about this case is that the part that matters to us is "Area C". This is because $x=0$, so $f(x)=g(x)=0$. Thus this will be the only nonzero area in the entire picture!

Now, the other critical piece of intuition is to observe how differentiability implies that this Area C goes to $0$ too fast to be included in the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$. To see this, I recommend [Paramanand Singh's wonderful answer to this very question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3603162/429987).

I especially recommended the latter part of that answer, on how the derivatives are basically good local linear approximations $ax,bx$. Then if we multiply two of those together, we get a quadratic $abx^2$, which at it's extreme point, has slope $0$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am glad you liked my answer. +1 for images and yes that explains the product rule nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that f and g are differentiable is important not because you need to find the derivative of f(x)g(x), but because this means that the two functions are continuous and will not have a cusp or asymptote. This means that rational functions and logarithmic functions are not a possibility - which will be important.

For f(x)g(x) to result in x for all x on R, it must be the case the f and g cancel each other out and leave only x behind. This is not possible if f and g are both polynomials as their product will increase in degree and will not result in x. Trigonometric functions will either have asymptotes or a limited range. Finding a way to prove that there is no pair of functions that will be both differentiable and cancel each other out cleanly will be the way forward.